# Slackware(64) 14.2 + chroot + xfce4-session + audio + (NV-)GLX?

Tags: bash, chroot, xephyr

Just to make it easier to mount my Slackware 14.2 Installation, I put it on another partition (it's 32 Bits 100% real native).

I can start xfce4-session like root user (but that is not the thing I need) :

[image: ch"root"]

I need to know if someone can help me with the follow things

1 - Redirect audio to host, because

[image: i don't had any sound from chroot]

2 - Is possible use 3D,DRI with Nvidia ? I saw something on a Gentoo forum, but I don't understand it)

[image: Nvidia, 2D/3D possible?]

3 - Hide some commands and/or outputs from my script :
The lines are :

```
local being added to access control list

export DISPLAY=localhost:1 2>/dev/null

exit
```

and when I close the Xephyr window, this shows up afterwards:

```
-su: línea 3: $'\E[01mHP': no se encontró la orden
```

[image: chroot & xephyr]

My script "slack32-chroot" content :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo '
Autor ----------------> Inukaze ( Venezuela )
Sitio ----------------> https://goo.gl/ij6WqW
Correo-E -------------> bloginukaze@gmail.com
Licencia -------------> GPL 2
'
#Establecer mediante la variable "$OBJETIVO" 
#La particion con una distribucion a la cual se accedera mediante chroot
export OBJETIVO="/media/Slack32"

#Prevenir que se autoejecuten las funciones que se definiran despues
unset montar
unset desmontar
unset MensajeBase

#Establecer y definir funciones :
function MensajeBase()
{
echo -e "\nLa forma correcta de utilizar este guion es :\n$0 «montar» , «montar_xephyr» ó «desmontar», Por ejemplo : \n"
echo -e "$0 montar"
echo -e "$0 montar_xephyr"
echo -e "$0 desmontar\n"
}

function montar(){
#Preparar acceso para programas de entorno grafico :
export DISPLAY=:0.0 2>/dev/null
xhost + local 2>/dev/null

#Montar todo de una vez para una distro de 32 Bits (En este caso Slackware32 14.2) : 
mount --rbind /proc                         "$OBJETIVO/proc"                        ; \
mount --make-rslave                         "$OBJETIVO/proc"                        ; \
mount --rbind /sys                              "$OBJETIVO/sys"                         ; \
mount --make-rslave                         "$OBJETIVO/sys"                         ; \
mount --rbind /dev                          "$OBJETIVO/dev"                         ; \
mount --make-rslave                         "$OBJETIVO/dev"                         ; \
mount --rbind /run                              "$OBJETIVO/run"                         ; \
mount --make-rslave                         "$OBJETIVO/run"                         ; \
mount --rbind /tmp                          "$OBJETIVO/tmp"                         ; \
mount --make-rslave                         "$OBJETIVO/tmp"                         ; \
mount --bind /etc/fstab                     "$OBJETIVO/etc/fstab"                   ; \
mount --bind /etc/hostname          "$OBJETIVO/etc/hostname"        ; \
mount --bind /etc/hosts                     "$OBJETIVO/etc/hosts"               ; \
mount --bind /etc/resolv.conf           "$OBJETIVO/etc/resolv.conf"     ; \

cat << EOF | linux32 chroot "$OBJETIVO"
export DISPLAY=localhost:1 2>/dev/null
EOF

linux32 chroot                                  "$OBJETIVO" /bin/bash -l                ; \
umount -l                                           "$OBJETIVO"                                 ; \
mount -a 2>/dev/null
}


function xephyr(){
#Copiar archivo de autorizacion X.Org :
rm -f "$OBJETIVO/home/inukaze/.Xauthority"
rm -f "$OBJETIVO/root/.Xauthority"
cp -f "/home/inukaze/.Xauthority" "$OBJETIVO/root/.Xauthority"
cp -f "/home/inukaze/.Xauthority" "$OBJETIVO/home/inukaze/.Xauthority"
chown inukaze:users "$OBJETIVO/home/inukaze/.Xauthority"

if [ ! -f "$OBJETIVO/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config" ] ; then
# Prevenir el error « /usr/libexec/Xorg.wrap: Only console users are allowed to run the X server »
echo '# Xwrapper.config (Debian X Window System server wrapper configuration file)
#
# This file was generated by the post-installation script of the x11-common
# package using values from the debconf database.
#
# See the Xwrapper.config(5) manual page for more information.
#
# This file is automatically updated on upgrades of the x11-common package
# *only* if it has not been modified since the last upgrade of that package.
#
# If you have edited this file but would like it to be automatically updated
# again, run the following command as root:
#   dpkg-reconfigure x11-common
#allowed_users=console
allowed_users=anybody' | tee "$OBJETIVO/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config"
fi

#Preparar acceso para programas de entorno grafico :
export DISPLAY=:0.0 2>/dev/null
xhost + local 2>/dev/null

#Montar todo de una vez para una distro de 32 Bits (En este caso Slackware32 14.2) : 
mount --rbind /proc                         "$OBJETIVO/proc"                        ; \
mount --make-rslave                         "$OBJETIVO/proc"                        ; \
mount --rbind /sys                              "$OBJETIVO/sys"                         ; \
mount --make-rslave                         "$OBJETIVO/sys"                         ; \
mount --rbind /dev                          "$OBJETIVO/dev"                         ; \
mount --make-rslave                         "$OBJETIVO/dev"                         ; \
mount --rbind /run                              "$OBJETIVO/run"                         ; \
mount --make-rslave                         "$OBJETIVO/run"                         ; \
mount --rbind /tmp                          "$OBJETIVO/tmp"                         ; \
mount --make-rslave                         "$OBJETIVO/tmp"                         ; \
mount --bind /etc/fstab                     "$OBJETIVO/etc/fstab"                   ; \
mount --bind /etc/hostname          "$OBJETIVO/etc/hostname"        ; \
mount --bind /etc/hosts                     "$OBJETIVO/etc/hosts"               ; \
mount --bind /etc/resolv.conf           "$OBJETIVO/etc/resolv.conf"     ; \

cat << EOF | linux32 chroot "$OBJETIVO"
export DISPLAY=localhost:1 2>/dev/null
EOF

linux32 chroot                                  "$OBJETIVO" /bin/bash -l        <<"EOT"
#Primero Detectar Particiones, Crear Directorios dentro de /media y finalmente montarlas
#Nombre De Particion :
#   NPD1="1SlackIni"    # Esta es la particion /boot de la particion que estoy usando en chroot
    NPD2="72GB"
    NPD3="Compartido"
    NPD4="2SlackIni"
#   NPD5="Slack64"  #Esta es la particion Anfrition, asi que realmente no la necesito para esto.
#   NPD6="Slack32"  #Esta es la que estoy usando en chroot
    NPD7="2Compartir"
#Parte de la Particion
#   PPD1=$(blkid | grep "$NPD1" | cut -c01-09)
    PPD2=$(blkid | grep "$NPD2" | cut -c01-09)
    PPD3=$(blkid | grep "$NPD3" | cut -c01-09)
    PPD4=$(blkid | grep "$NPD4" | cut -c01-09)
#   PPD5=$(blkid | grep "$NPD5" | cut -c01-09)
#   PPD6=$(blkid | grep "$NPD6" | cut -c01-09)
    PPD7=$(blkid | grep "$NPD7" | cut -c01-09)
$(mkdir -p /media/"$NPD2" ; mount "$PPD2" /media/"$NPD2" )
$(mkdir -p /media/"$NPD3" ; mount "$PPD3" /media/"$NPD3" )
$(mkdir -p /media/"$NPD4" ; mount "$PPD4" /media/"$NPD4" )
$(mkdir -p /media/"$NPD7" ; mount "$PPD7" /media/"$NPD7" )
$(su - inukaze)
$(Xephyr -ac -screen 1070x888 -br -reset -terminate :1.0 2>/dev/null &)
$(export DISPLAY=:1.0)
$(DISPLAY=:1 /usr/bin/xfce4-session -- :1 2>/dev/null)
EOT

umount -l                                           "$OBJETIVO"                                 ; \
mount -a 2>/dev/null
}

function desmontar(){
# Desmontar
umount -l           "$OBJETIVO"                         ; \
mount -a 2>/dev/null
}


#Este guión necesita ser ejecutado como SuperUsuario
#o en su defecto con permisos administrativos suficientes
#Para montar / desmontar particiones.
if [ "$(whoami)" != root ]; then

    echo
    echo
    echo 'Por favor ejecuta este guion como SuperUsuario (root)'
    echo
    echo 'Utilize este guión bajo su Propio Riesgro'
    echo 'El Autor , o sea yo , no me hago responsable'
    echo 'de las consecuencias imprevistas que puedan'
    echo 'acontecer en tu sistema operativo'
    echo
else
# Proceder en caso de tener los permisos suficientes para montar/desmontar particiones :

#Si el usuario no pasa ningun parametro indicar como se usa este guion
            if [ -z "$1" ]; then
                    MensajeBase
            fi

#Guion : Aqui se ha definido como se utilizara este guion correctamente para montar o desmontar la particion Objetivo
#Entrada : Cualquier palabra pasada por el parametro $1 sera convertida en minusculas
Entrada=$(echo "$1" | tr -s  '[:upper:]'  '[:lower:]')

            if [ "$Entrada" == "montar" ]; then
                    montar
            fi

            if [ "$Entrada" == "xephyr" ]; then
                    xephyr
            fi

            if [ "$Entrada" == "desmontar" ]; then
                    desmontar
            fi

#Finalizar la condicion globar de requerir usar el SuperUsuario o en su defectos persmisos administrativos
#Para poder (des)montar particiones :
fi

#Finalizar este guion sin problemas :
exit 0 2>/dev/null
```

This is a copy from [LinuxQuestions.org](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=6309616#post6309616)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Because I don't use pulseaudio in the chroot the audio solution fix is just delete the file `/etc/asound.conf`

   ```
   rm -rf /usr/asound.conf
   ```
2. The access to 3D/DRI requires two things, the first is edit the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and add

   ```
   Section "Files"
   #    ModulePath "/usr/lib64/nvidia-304.137/xorg"
        ModulePath "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
   EndSection
   ```

   You must first check in where path are the files of "modules and extensions" for X.Org, after adding some extensions and the `+iglx` parameter to enable access to glx, xephyr command now is :

   ```
   $(Xephyr -ac -screen 1070x888 -br -reset -terminate -render :1.0 \
   +extension Composite \
   +extension DAMAGE \
   +extension DOUBLE-BUFFER \
   +extension DPMS \
   +extension GLX \
   +extension NV-GLX \
   +extension RANDR \
   +extension RENDER \
   +extension X-Resource \
   +extension XFIXES \
   +xinerama \
   +iglx \
   2>/dev/null &)
   ```

That is all I needed for access from my real installation of Slackware64 14.2 to my real installtion of Slackware32 14.2 on another partition with audio and 3D/DRI.

My whole script is now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo '
Autor ----------------> Inukaze ( Venezuela )
Sitio ----------------> https://goo.gl/ij6WqW
Correo-E -------------> bloginukaze@gmail.com
Licencia -------------> GPL 2
'
#Establecer mediante la variable "$OBJETIVO" 
#La particion con una distribucion a la cual se accedera mediante chroot
export OBJETIVO="/media/Slack32"

#Prevenir que se autoejecuten las funciones que se definiran despues
unset montar
unset desmontar
unset MensajeBase

#Establecer y definir funciones :
function MensajeBase()
{
echo -e "\nLa forma correcta de utilizar este guion es :\n$0 «montar» , «montar_xephyr» ó «desmontar», Por ejemplo : \n"
echo -e "$0 montar"
echo -e "$0 montar_xephyr"
echo -e "$0 desmontar\n"
}

function montar(){
#Preparar acceso para programas de entorno grafico :
export DISPLAY=:0.0 2>/dev/null
xhost + local 2>/dev/null

#Montar todo de una vez para una distro de 32 Bits (En este caso Slackware32 14.2) : 
mount --rbind /proc                         "$OBJETIVO/proc"                        ; \
mount --make-rslave                         "$OBJETIVO/proc"                        ; \
mount --rbind /sys                              "$OBJETIVO/sys"                         ; \
mount --make-rslave                         "$OBJETIVO/sys"                         ; \
mount --rbind /dev                          "$OBJETIVO/dev"                         ; \
mount --make-rslave                         "$OBJETIVO/dev"                         ; \
mount --rbind /run                              "$OBJETIVO/run"                         ; \
mount --make-rslave                         "$OBJETIVO/run"                         ; \
mount --rbind /tmp                          "$OBJETIVO/tmp"                         ; \
mount --make-rslave                         "$OBJETIVO/tmp"                         ; \
mount --bind /etc/fstab                     "$OBJETIVO/etc/fstab"                   ; \
mount --bind /etc/hostname          "$OBJETIVO/etc/hostname"        ; \
mount --bind /etc/hosts                     "$OBJETIVO/etc/hosts"               ; \
mount --bind /etc/resolv.conf           "$OBJETIVO/etc/resolv.conf"     ; \

cat << EOF | linux32 chroot "$OBJETIVO"
export DISPLAY=localhost:1 2>/dev/null
EOF

linux32 chroot                                  "$OBJETIVO" /bin/bash -l                ; \
umount -l                                           "$OBJETIVO"                                 ; \
mount -a 2>/dev/null
}


function xephyr(){
#Copiar archivo de autorizacion X.Org :
rm -f "$OBJETIVO/home/inukaze/.Xauthority"
rm -f "$OBJETIVO/root/.Xauthority"
cp -f "/home/inukaze/.Xauthority" "$OBJETIVO/root/.Xauthority"
cp -f "/home/inukaze/.Xauthority" "$OBJETIVO/home/inukaze/.Xauthority"

#Audio :
#rm -rf                                                 "$OBJETIVO/etc/asound.conf"
#cp -f "/etc/asound.state"                      "$OBJETIVO/etc/asound.state"

#Video :
#cp -f /usr/lib/libGL.so.304.137-nvidia "$OBJETIVO/usr/lib/libGL.so.304.137-nvidia"
#cp -f /usr/lib/libGL.so.304.137-nvidia "$OBJETIVO/usr/lib/libGL.so.304.137"
#cp -f /usr/lib/libGL.so.1.2.0                  "$OBJETIVO/usr/lib/libGL.so.1.2.0"
#cp -f /usr/lib/libGL.so                                "$OBJETIVO/usr/lib/libGL.so"
#cp -f /usr/lib/libGL.la-nvidia                 "$OBJETIVO/usr/lib/libGL.la-nvidia"

chown inukaze:users "$OBJETIVO/home/inukaze/.Xauthority"

if [ ! -f "$OBJETIVO/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config" ] ; then
# Prevenir el error « /usr/libexec/Xorg.wrap: Only console users are allowed to run the X server »
echo '# Xwrapper.config (Debian X Window System server wrapper configuration file)
#
# This file was generated by the post-installation script of the x11-common
# package using values from the debconf database.
#
# See the Xwrapper.config(5) manual page for more information.
#
# This file is automatically updated on upgrades of the x11-common package
# *only* if it has not been modified since the last upgrade of that package.
#
# If you have edited this file but would like it to be automatically updated
# again, run the following command as root:
#   dpkg-reconfigure x11-common
#allowed_users=console
allowed_users=anybody' | tee "$OBJETIVO/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config"
fi

#Preparar acceso para programas de entorno grafico :
$(export DISPLAY=:1.0)
$(xhost + local 2>/dev/null)

#Montar todo de una vez para una distro de 32 Bits (En este caso Slackware32 14.2) : 
mount --rbind /proc                                                 "$OBJETIVO/proc"                                                    ; \
mount --make-rslave                                                 "$OBJETIVO/proc"                                                    ; \
mount --rbind /sys                                                      "$OBJETIVO/sys"                                                     ; \
mount --make-rslave                                                 "$OBJETIVO/sys"                                                     ; \
mount --rbind /dev                                                  "$OBJETIVO/dev"                                                     ; \
mount --make-rslave                                                 "$OBJETIVO/dev"                                                     ; \
mount --rbind /run                                                      "$OBJETIVO/run"                                                     ; \
mount --make-rslave                                                 "$OBJETIVO/run"                                                     ; \
mount --rbind /tmp                                                  "$OBJETIVO/tmp"                                                     ; \
mount --make-rslave                                                 "$OBJETIVO/tmp"                                                     ; \
mount --rbind /var/run/dbus                                     "$OBJETIVO/var/run/dbus"                                        ; \
mount --make-rslave                                                 "$OBJETIVO/var/run/dbus"                                        ; \
mount --rbind /var/lib/dbus                                     "$OBJETIVO/var/lib/dbus"                                        ; \
mount --make-rslave                                                 "$OBJETIVO/var/lib/dbus"                                        ; \
mount --rbind /etc/X11                                              "$OBJETIVO/etc/X11"                                             ; \
mount --make-rslave                                                 "$OBJETIVO/etc/X11"                                             ; \
mount --rbind /usr/X11R6                                        "$OBJETIVO/usr/X11R6"                                           ; \
mount --make-rslave                                                 "$OBJETIVO/usr/X11R6"                                           ; \
mount --rbind /lib/modules                                      "$OBJETIVO/lib/modules"                                     ; \
mount --make-rslave                                                 "$OBJETIVO/lib/modules"                                     ; \
mount --bind /etc/fstab                                             "$OBJETIVO/etc/fstab"                                               ; \
mount --bind /etc/hostname                                  "$OBJETIVO/etc/hostname"                                    ; \
mount --bind /etc/hosts                                             "$OBJETIVO/etc/hosts"                                           ; \
mount --bind /etc/resolv.conf                                   "$OBJETIVO/etc/resolv.conf"                                 ; \
#NV_GLX#mount --bind /usr/lib/libnvidia-glcore.so.304.137   "$OBJETIVO/usr/lib/libnvidia-glcore.so.304.137" ; \
#NV_GLX#mount --bind /usr/lib/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.304.137  "$OBJETIVO/usr/lib/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.304.137"    ; \
#NV_GLX#mount --bind /usr/lib/libGLEW.so.1.13.0                 "$OBJETIVO/usr/lib/libGLEW.so.1.13.0"                   ; \
#NV_GLX#mount --bind /usr/lib/libGLEW.so.1.13                       "$OBJETIVO/usr/lib/libGLEW.so.1.13"                     ; \
#NV_GLX#mount --bind /usr/lib/libGLEW.so                                "$OBJETIVO/usr/lib/libGLEW.so"                              ; \
#NV_GLX#mount --bind /usr/lib/libGLU.so.1.3.1                       "$OBJETIVO/usr/lib/libGLU.so.1.3.1"                     ; \
#NV_GLX#mount --bind /usr/lib/libGLU.so.1                               "$OBJETIVO/usr/lib/libGLU.so.1"                             ; \
#NV_GLX#mount --bind /usr/lib/libGLU.so                                 "$OBJETIVO/usr/lib/libGLU.so"                               ; \
#NV_GLX#mount --bind /usr/lib/libGLU.la                                 "$OBJETIVO/usr/lib/libGLU.la"                                   ; \
#NV_GLX#mount --bind /usr/lib/libGL.so.304.137-nvidia           "$OBJETIVO/usr/lib/libGL.so.304.137-nvidia"     ; \
#NV_GLX#mount --bind /usr/lib/libGL.so.1.2.0                            "$OBJETIVO/usr/lib/libGL.so.1.2.0"                          ; \
#NV_GLX#mount --bind /usr/lib/libGL.so.1                                "$OBJETIVO/usr/lib/libGL.so.1"                              ; \
#NV_GLX#mount --bind /usr/lib/libGL.so                                  "$OBJETIVO/usr/lib/libGL.so"                                    ; \
#NV_GLX#mount --bind /usr/lib/libGL.la-nvidia                       "$OBJETIVO/usr/lib/libGL.la-nvidia"                     ; \
#NV_GLX#mount --bind /usr/lib/libGL.la                                  "$OBJETIVO/usr/lib/libGL.la"                                    ; \
#AUDIO#mount --bind /usr/lib/libasound.so.2.0.0                 "$OBJETIVO/usr/lib/libasound.so.2.0.0"                  ; \
#AUDIO#mount --bind /usr/lib/libasound.so.2                     "$OBJETIVO/usr/lib/libasound.so.2"                      ; \
#AUDIO#mount --bind /usr/lib/libasound.so                           "$OBJETIVO/usr/lib/libasound.so"                            ; \
#AUDIO#mount --bind /usr/lib/libasound.la                           "$OBJETIVO/usr/lib/libasound.la"                            ; \


cat << EOF | linux32 chroot "$OBJETIVO"
$(export DISPLAY=:1.0 2>/dev/null) 
EOF

linux32 chroot                                  "$OBJETIVO" /bin/bash -l        <<"EOT"
#Primero Detectar Particiones, Crear Directorios dentro de /media y finalmente montarlas
#Nombre De Particion :
#   NPD1="1SlackIni"    # Esta es la particion /boot de la particion que estoy usando en chroot
    NPD2="72GB"
    NPD3="Compartido"
    NPD4="2SlackIni"
#   NPD5="Slack64"  #Esta es la particion Anfrition, asi que realmente no la necesito para esto.
#   NPD6="Slack32"  #Esta es la que estoy usando en chroot
    NPD7="2Compartir"
#Parte de la Particion
#   PPD1=$(blkid | grep "$NPD1" | cut -c01-09)
    PPD2=$(blkid | grep "$NPD2" | cut -c01-09)
    PPD3=$(blkid | grep "$NPD3" | cut -c01-09)
    PPD4=$(blkid | grep "$NPD4" | cut -c01-09)
#   PPD5=$(blkid | grep "$NPD5" | cut -c01-09)
#   PPD6=$(blkid | grep "$NPD6" | cut -c01-09)
    PPD7=$(blkid | grep "$NPD7" | cut -c01-09)
$(mkdir -p /media/"$NPD2" ; mount "$PPD2" /media/"$NPD2" )
$(mkdir -p /media/"$NPD3" ; mount "$PPD3" /media/"$NPD3" )
$(mkdir -p /media/"$NPD4" ; mount "$PPD4" /media/"$NPD4" )
$(mkdir -p /media/"$NPD7" ; mount "$PPD7" /media/"$NPD7" )
$(su - inukaze)

$(Xephyr -ac -screen 1070x888 -br -reset -terminate -render :1.0 \
+extension Composite \
+extension DAMAGE \
+extension DOUBLE-BUFFER \
+extension DPMS \
+extension GLX \
+extension NV-GLX \
+extension RANDR \
+extension RENDER \
+extension X-Resource \
+extension XFIXES \
+xinerama \
+iglx \
2>/dev/null &)

$(export DISPLAY=:1.0)
$(DISPLAY=:1 /usr/bin/xfce4-session -- :1 2>/dev/null) 

##DESACTIVADO##$(DISPLAY=:1 /usr/bin/startx -- :1 2>/dev/null)  #Inicia en otra tty con (NV-)GLX a pantalla completa
EOT

umount -l                                           "$OBJETIVO"                                 ; \
mount -a 2>/dev/null
}

function desmontar(){

# Desmontar

umount -l           "$OBJETIVO"                         ; \
mount -a 2>/dev/null

}


#Este guión necesita ser ejecutado como SuperUsuario
#o en su defecto con permisos administrativos suficientes
#Para montar / desmontar particiones.

if [ "$(whoami)" != root ]; then

    echo
    echo
    echo 'Por favor ejecuta este guion como SuperUsuario (root)'
    echo
    echo 'Utilice este guión bajo su Propio Riesgo'
    echo 'El Autor , o sea yo , no me hago responsable'
    echo 'de las consecuencias imprevistas que puedan'
    echo 'acontecer en tu sistema operativo'
    echo
else

# Proceder en caso de tener los permisos suficientes para montar/desmontar particiones :

#Si el usuario no pasa ningún parámetro indicar como se usa este guion

            if [ -z "$1" ]; then
                    MensajeBase
            fi

#Guion : Aquí se ha definido como se utilizara este guion correctamente para montar o desmontar la partición Objetivo
#Entrada : Cualquier palabra pasada por el parámetro $1 sera convertida en minúsculas

Entrada=$(echo "$1" | tr -s  '[:upper:]'  '[:lower:]')

            if [ "$Entrada" == "montar" ]; then
                    montar
            fi

            if [ "$Entrada" == "xephyr" ]; then
                    xephyr
            fi

            if [ "$Entrada" == "desmontar" ]; then
                    desmontar
            fi

#Finalizar la condición global de requerir usar el SuperUsuario o en su defectos permisos administrativos
#Para poder (des)montar particiones :

fi

#Finalizar este guion sin problemas :

$(exit 0)
```

Notes :

a. The #AUDIO & #NV-GLX section are thing are really don't need it

b. Because making test with that, I try to compile nvidia-legacy304 drivers directly on chroot and that result very bad, right now I not had 3D/DRI on my Slackware64 14.2 because I can't compile "nvidia-legeacy304-kernel" I just got the following error :

```
Creating directory NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.137
Verifying archive integrity... OK
Uncompressing NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux-x86_64 


304.137................................................................................................................................................................
If you are using a Linux 2.4 kernel, please make sure
you either have configured kernel sources matching your
kernel or the correct set of kernel headers installed
on your system.

If you are using a Linux 2.6 kernel, please make sure
you have configured kernel sources matching your kernel
installed on your system. If you specified a separate
output directory using either the "KBUILD_OUTPUT" or
the "O" KBUILD parameter, make sure to specify this
directory with the SYSOUT environment variable or with
the equivalent nvidia-installer command line option.

Depending on where and how the kernel sources (or the
kernel headers) were installed, you may need to specify
their location with the SYSSRC environment variable or
the equivalent nvidia-installer command line option.

*** Unable to determine the target kernel version. ***

makefile:53: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'select_makefile'
```